# I am getting KeyError: 'D.O.A' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: for almost every column name I use as parameter

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

My data has a column named D.O.A which has dates now when I do this

dframe1['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dframe1['D.O.A']).month

OR

dframe.set_index('D.O.A')

I am getting the same error again for all. The error is-

KeyError: 'D.O.A'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

This is the data I was using

Serial Num  IPD No. D.O.A.  Time    D.O.D.  PATIENT NAME

1   7516    23-Apr-19   4:15: AM    23-Apr-19   Baby MAHAK

2   7510    22-Apr-19   1:35: PM    23-Apr-19   Mr. TEJPAL

3   7509    22-Apr-19   12:45: PM   22-Apr-19   Mr. SUBHASH

Comment: Please add the output of `dframe1.columns`

Comment: Mention your input and expected output as well.

Comment: Evidently you don't have a column with that name.  Beyond that we can't help you because we don't have your dataframe to look at.  It's your responsibility to provide us with a enough information.

Comment: I have edited the question, and added the dataset,

Comment: please see. Thank You.

Comment: This is the data I was using

Serial Num IPD No. D.O.A. Time D.O.D. PATIENT NAME

1 7516 23-Apr-19 4:15: AM 23-Apr-19 Baby MAHAK

2 7510 22-Apr-19 1:35: PM 23-Apr-19 Mr. TEJPAL

3 7509 22-Apr-19 12:45: PM 22-Apr-19 Mr. SUBHASH

Comment: It looks like your data has a period at the end of "D.O.A." and your code does not.